# PostgreSQL: not all data from a table is returned

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I migrated a table in pgAdmin via .csv-file. When I open the table in pgAdmin I can see all the data as expected. So the migration seemed to work.

**My problem:**
When querying the table, most of the data aren't returned, even if I see them in pgAdmin.
The strange thing: when I edit the data manually in pgAdmin and hit "save" then the data is returned correctly.

I have no idea why this happens. Can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: run:  select count(*) from <table>;  to see the exact number of row.

Comment: When I run the query above I get the correct number of rows. Puuh, this is confusing. So why do I only get the data, if I rewrite them manually in pgAdmin? Any ideas?

Comment: How are you querying the data?

Comment: Here is an example: select * from "Items" where "category1" = 'English' - this returns 0 rows, but there are multiple rows in the table. I tried to use the query tool in pgAdmin and also psql.

Comment: Your category1 field contains something other than 'English'. Did you check for leading/trailing whitespace? What if you try `LIKE '%English%'`?

Comment: @clamp: Thanks a lot! You are right. The problem is whitespaces after the words (f.ex. "English"). Can you tell me why whitespaces are added when migrating data with .csv in pgAdmin or psql (I tried both)? And how can I remove them? Btw, you can write it as answer so I can mark it as solved!

Comment: If you have spaces at the end of your data you can use `trim()`:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here is an example: select * from "Items" where "category1" = 'English' - this returns 0 rows*

If you are seeing this, your `category1` fields do not contain the value `'English'`. You did a csv import. It might have happened that the values in your CSV file were padded with spaces. You can correct that in your table using the `trim()` function:

```
update "Items" set category1 = trim(both from category1);
```

This will strip off leading and trailing spaces. If it's other characters you need to remove you can specify them in yor `trim()`call.

```
update "Items" set category1 = trim(both ' chars' from category1);
```

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html)

Comment: Thank you so much. You helped me a lot! I didn't know, that whitespaces can be added automatically. The trim() function works.